# How to get accurate elapsed time between send and receive a socket transmission?

Tags: c#, sockets, xamarin, tcp

I need to synchronize the time between server and client, I want a milisseconds transmission time. Due the caracteristics of TCP protocol I believe to have some inner control about time sended and timer received a TCP socket, but I did not found how to get it using my TcpSocketClient.

If you not undestood yet, the server says (send) his hour to the client, and client have your clock sychronized with this hour, bou I need to adjust the hour adding the time to send the time from the server to the client!

Avoid NTP use answers, my client is a mobile and I wil just use the new time for the App, I will not change the time of the device.

Comment: You probably won't get the accuracy you are looking for.  Windows uses Timer Tick to move data from application to Ethernet driver and back from Ethernet driver so the accuracy is how often the Timer Tick Events are processed in Windows.

Comment: You can use NTP without actually changing the device's clock. Why don't you want to use NTP? Seems like having both ends contact a common NTP server and use the information to generate internal clock offsets for synchronization would be best. In any case, as asked the question is unclear and very broad. Why the synchronization requirement? What kind of precision and accuracy is needed? What is the precise behavior you want to achieve? It would be better for you to try something, then if you have trouble post a question with a good [mcve].

Comment: I not want to use NTP due needs more net authorizations from the user (differents in each platform, android, ios, windows) to the App. I found in the Internet that this problem has no precise solution without know the lag time. So, I will do 5 communications between server and client to calculate the average time and divide to half (I will believe to have same time to go and to come back). The accuration is need because 2 clients updates records those will send to the server and the server need to choose the more recently.

Answer (score 0):

You will want your client make a call to the server to return a server timestamp. Before the client makes the call, have the client record a high precision timestamp. When the server returns its time, calculate the delta from client send time to receipt of the server response. You can then subtract half of the roundtrip time from the server timestamp. This will give you a close approximation of server time. Repeat more frequently and avg out deltas to get higher precision.